# mysql to postgresql query conversion question (parameters)

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Currently, I am trying to convert a php program from querying a Mysql database to a Postgresql database. My understanding is that Mysql accepts question marks as placeholders while pg_query_params requires placeholders to be numbered.

For example, here is the php pulling from a Mysql db

```
private function setMinPrice($value) {
    $this->setQuery("where", " AND e.Price >= ?");
    $params = array($value);
    $this->updateParams("d", $params);
    }

private function setMaxPrice($value) {
    $this->setQuery("where", " AND e.Price <= ?");
    $params = array($value);
    $this->updateParams("d", $params);
    }
```

The thing is, Postgres requires the parameters to be numbered ($1,$2,$3, etc.). The number needed for setMaxPrice depends on whether the user entered minimum price as an input (and therefore called setMinPrice). The Postgres placeholder value for setMinPrice (to substitute in for the question mark) would be $1, but for setMaxPrice it could be $1 or $2  depending on whether setMinPrice was called. Any suggestions on how to put in clean Postgres-friendly placeholders that can accept a varying number of parameters?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review the help section [ask]. Specifically what have you tried? What was wrong with it? It seems the MySql version is calling separate functions which each accepts an array.  Postgres functions will gladly accept arrays providing each element is of the same data type. Why not follow that same logic in Postgres? For additional help post sample data, as text - **no images** and the desired results of that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a second parameter `&$param_count` (passed by reference) that contains the number of parameters so far. You increment it in the function and use it to construct `$1`, `$2` etc.